# How does a python web server overcomes GIL

Tags: python, django, concurrency, webserver

Any web server might have to handle a lot of requests at the same time. As python interpreter actually has GIL constraint, how concurrency is implemented?

Do they use multiple processes and use IPC for state sharing?

Comment: What state sharing? The whole point of web requests is that each is independent, there is no shared state.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: State as in "Session Attributes" (e.g. in Java Servlet Applications), i.e. the information kept on the server side, usually relying on HTTP cookie holding a session ID for identifying a session the request belongs to. Web Browser can submit many requests in parallel within the same session. The server should have access to the session attributes given the session ID.

Answer (score 3):

You usually have many workers(i.e. gunicorn), each being dispatched with independent requests. Everything else(concurrency related) is handled by the database so it is abstracted from you.

You don't need IPC, you just need a "single source of truth", which will be the RDBMS, a cache server(redis, memcached), etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, requests can be handled independently. However, servers want to *simultaneously* handle them in order to keep the number of requests that can be handled per time at a maximum.

The implementation of this concept of *concurrency* depends on the webserver.

Some implementations may have a fixed number of threads or processes for handling requests. If all are in use, additional requests have to wait until being handled.

Another possibility is that a process or thread is spawned for each request. Spawning a process for each request leads to an absurd memory and cpu overhead. Spawning lightweight threads is better. Doing so, you can serve hundreds of clients per second. However, also threads bring their management overhead, manifesting itself in high memory and CPU consumption.

For serving thousands of clients per second, an event-driven architecture based on asynchronous coroutines is a state-of-the-art solution. It enables the server to serve clients at a high rate without spawning zillions of threads. On the [Wikipedia page of the so-called C10k problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) you find a list of web servers. Among those, many make use of this architecture.

Coroutines are available for Python, too. Have look at http://www.gevent.org/. That's why a Python WSGI app based on e.g [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) + gevent is an extremely performant solution.

Comment: "Spawning a process for each request leads to an absurd memory and cpu overhead." This is completely dependent on the OS.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: for which OS is this not true ("absurd" was meant in comparison to the overhead of threading or coroutines)?

Comment: It's not that it isn't true, it's that the exact definition of "absurd" varies; Windows is a big steaming pile of blessed excrement when it comes to starting new processes, but *nices tend to be quite a bit lighter in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As normal. Web serving is mostly I/O-bound, and the GIL is released during I/O operations. So either threading is used without any special accommodations, or an event loop (such as Twisted) is used.

Comment: I am not talking about waiting/receiving request. I am talking about handling them. For instance, if I receive a request, I may have to do some processing, like checking various POST or GET requests, which is usually written as python code. So how does python interpreter will execute these blocks of code concurrently as it has GIL constraint.

Comment: This is simply untrue. Not all workloads are IO bound. It is entirely common to see web servers with maxed-out CPUs. It depends on the application being run.